# php / mysql pagination - count from multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm trying to follow this pagination tutorial http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination to add pagination to my search page i've built. The following line from the tutorial:

```
$sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM numbers";
```

I need it to count based on rows which match user inputted data that's being pulled in from a small form. This is the working query i was running before trying to add pagination

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Pictures WHERE (`RimWidth` LIKE '%".$RimWidth."%') AND (`TyreWidth` LIKE '%".$TyreWidth."%') AND (`Aspect` LIKE '%".$Aspect."%') AND (`TyreDia` LIKE '%".$TyreDia."%') AND (`TyreMan` LIKE '%".$TyreMan."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm unsure how i can add this. I've tried this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT FROM Pictures WHERE (`RimWidth` LIKE '%".$RimWidth."%') AND (`TyreWidth` LIKE '%".$TyreWidth."%') AND (`Aspect` LIKE '%".$Aspect."%') AND (`TyreDia` LIKE '%".$TyreDia."%') AND (`TyreMan` LIKE '%".$TyreMan."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

But it just errors out.

How do i need to format the query?

Comment: COUNT(*)..You missd it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error using ***`COUNT`*** instead of ***`COUNT(expression)`***, so you have to change your query so that you use ***`SELECT COUNT(*)`*** as in the first example you gave.

**EDIT** That's how you can get the exact count:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pictures WHERE (`RimWidth` LIKE '%".$RimWidth."%') AND (`TyreWidth` LIKE '%".$TyreWidth."%') AND (`Aspect` LIKE '%".$Aspect."%') AND (`TyreDia` LIKE '%".$TyreDia."%') AND (`TyreMan` LIKE '%".$TyreMan."%')";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: thanks, i did try with a * and using your code above give me this error `Fatal error: SQL in /mounted-storage/home34b/sub001/sc27915-YPZT/domain.com/searchresults.php on line 152` - line 152 is - `$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);`

Comment: As I wrote you before - I believe you're querying the string and then using the resulted resource as a new query in yet another mysql_query call

Comment: Don't pass $sql (which contains a DB resource) to another mysql_query method. You have your results already in $sql. 

Try the edited code above

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(*)` - skipped what to count.
Basically if your query is working but you need to get the count instead of actual data you should be good with replacing the columns you're trying to select with the `COUNT(*)`

One more thing. The result of your last code line is not the string itself. It's the resource that can be used to fetch the count you need.